# gdb print hex array in single byte mode

Tags: gdb

I'm using x/20x to print binary data in gdb

```
(gdb) x/20x 0x555555558df0
0x555555558df0: 0xfa1e0ff3  0x56415741  0x54415541  0x55fc8941
```

I wanted to print it in single byte like this:

```
0xf3 0x0f 0x1e 0xfa 0x41 0x57 0x41 0x56 ...
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

I've tried xb command as j6 suggested, but how can I print all of them in a single line?

```
(gdb) x/20xb 0x00007ffff7e84000
0x7ffff7e84000 <opendir>:   0xf3    0x0f    0x1e    0xfa    0x41    0x55    0x41    0x54
0x7ffff7e84008 <opendir+8>: 0x55    0x53    0x48    0x81    0xec    0xa8    0x00    0x00
0x7ffff7e84010 <opendir+16>:    0x00    0x64    0x48    0x8b
```

Comment: "I've tried ..." -- please avoid asking additional questions after you got the answer. `set width unlimited` will prevent GDB from wrapping its output. https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Screen-Size.html

Comment: @EmployedRussian set width unlimited does not work for me

Comment: Indeed, `width` has no effect on the `x` command. That seems like a bug. I figured out how to do what you asked for with a user-defined command, but the answer is too long for this comment. If you ask a separate question, I can answer there.

Comment: @EmployedRussian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148571/resolve-length-limit-with-xb-command-in-gdb

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try format `xb`, which is format `x` (hex), size `b` (bytes):

```
(gdb) x /8xb argv
0x7fffffffdc88: 0x20    0xe1    0xff    0xff    0xff    0x7f    0x00    0x00
```

`help x` is your friend.